# Do UK visits visa call your workplace for verification?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I am from India.  I have applied for UK visits visa for ten days. I do not want to inform about this holiday at my workplace since my boss hates me. Is there any way that my employers will get to know of my travel? As supporting document I am providing bank statements while applying for visa. However in my form I have mentioned my office name. Will they call my office to verify if I work there?

Comment: More to the point: what's your nationality?

Comment: Probably they will not call your office, but they _will_ refuse your visa for not including your salary slips, and evidence of any other deposits to your account.

Comment: They used to previously, but I believe they have stopped doing so. If your evidence is complete and truthful and can be corroborated from your evidences, they willn't. Else they might.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. I am from India. And I will be showing my salary slips.

Comment: Eventually aren't you going to need your boss to OK your time off work?

Answer (score 4):

If you are applying through the British issuing post in New Delhi, there is an almost certain likelihood that your application will go through a verification process that includes a first principles verification of your employment.

The mission employs about 60 Entry Clearance Assistants (Indian nationals hired locally) who are tasked with verification.

Consider this comment made by the [Chief Inspector](http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/)...

> In the Manila and New Delhi visa posts, we observed additional
>   verification checks being done by discrete teams of Entry Clearance
>   Assistants (ECAs), working alongside UKVI entry clearance staff and
>   RALON colleagues.27 Staff and managers in these teams were almost all
>   locally-engaged foreign nationals. Unlike most visa section staff,
>   team members had direct contact with applicants, sponsors and external
>   agencies. The sensitive nature of this activity and the significant
>   implications of a nongenuine check, including potentially a 10-year
>   entry ban on entry to the UK under Paragraph 320 of the Immigration
>   Rules, mean that adequate training and effective assurance are key
>   requirements.

His comment says *additional* verification checks.  These are on top of the standard verification checks that a high risk issuing post makes anyway.

My own observations have been that the ECA's in India are pretty good at what they do.  I have also seen lots of times when someone did not want their boss to know they were contemplating a trip to the UK (not just in India, but globally -- everywhere).  The only advice I can offer to help in that situation is to take it straight on and suck it up.  If your boss is surprised by a phone call from an ECA it will surely lead to a refusal and then matters will be worse.