# Refusal of UK Standard Visitor visa under v4.2(a)(c), v4.2 (e) and v4.3(a)(c)

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino and have just been refused a UK Standard Visitor visa. My husband is British and currently working as a groundworker. It is so frustrating because the officer stated that my husband doesn't have the funds to support me. They even said that they're not convinced that my husband and I have a genuine relationship! That is totally absurd.

What should we do next?

We are planning to go to the embassy next month to complain about the result. Appended is a scan of the refusal letter.

[image: Refusal note, 1st page]

[image: Refusal note, 2nd page]

Comment: My husband is a British national who lives in England.

Comment: That date of birth is not very well redacted; there are only 4 possibilities ...

Comment: "They even said that they're not convinced that my husband and I have a genuine relationship! That is totally absurd": what evidence did you submit to show that you are married?  Did you submit a marriage certificate?  Where did the wedding take place?  Was the marriage certificate in English?  If not, was it translated by a certified translator?  Was it properly authenticated?

Answer (score 7):

You are a Filipino national married to a Brit who lives in the UK. You applied for a Standard Visitor Visa under [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) of the rules and were refused.

Your application was in jeopardy from the beginning. The ECO tells us that you were refused a settlement visa under [Appendix FM](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-fm-family-members) and your appeal was dismissed. From that point forward, they will have it in mind that you want to get in to the UK and then make an [Article 8 claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_8_of_the_European_Convention_on_Human_Rights) to live there permanently. That's because the visitor visa will allow you to enter the UK without qualifying for a spouse visa and Article 8 will allow you to circumvent the hurdles in Appendix FM.  They have the inclination to think that way because lots of people do it.

We don't know your intentions, but for sure they were thinking that you are not a genuine visitor.

> It is so frustrating because the officer stated that my husband
>   doesn't have the funds to support me.

The ECO saw two bank accounts and concluded it's not enough to bring a visitor to the UK given that the visitor will not be earning holiday pay and has scant resources to begin with.  Given what's written it seems a fair assessment.  No doubt the ECO was thinking that if your husband could not support you under Appendix FM, he would be unable to support you under Appendix V. On balance, that's a fair conclusion.

Additionally the ECO gave his standard proportionality argument, namely that genuine visitors do not deplete their entire household reserves in order to get here. Simply stated genuine visitors use a fraction of their reserves and have a way to replenish their reserves when they return home.  While some people might have a premise for depleting their entire reserves for a visit, your evidence was not strong enough. Being unemployed was particularly unhelpful.

> He/she is even saying that he's not convinced that my husband and I
>   have a genuine relationship! That is totally absurd.

This is just icing on the cake. No doubt the ECO found something in your appeal paperwork or an assistant turned up something, or something like that. I wouldn't pay much attention to this because it pales in relation to the other refusal grounds.  If you are legally married (and not a sham marriage) they are required to acknowledge it.

They got you on 4.2 (a) + (c), and when you see that combination it's an indication that they think you will go underground in the UK and possibly become reliant on public funds.  Their reasoning is not about your relationship with your husband, a person doesn't have to be married to sponsor a visitor anyway.  Their reasoning is more about your lack of binding to the Philippines and having access to someone in the UK who would gladly harbour you illegally. In addition to harbouring, the ECO is also aware of how those situations can lead to domestic violence.

> We are planning to go to the Embassy next month to complain about the
>   result.

You will have a better and more fulfilling time going to the amusement park or to the beach. ECO's have a mandate from the government to make the *final decision* on visitor visas. They will explain that the remedy is to make a fresh application (which in your case is a strategy I would not endorse). In other words it will be a waste of time.  If you do go, you can print out this answer and show it to them as a way to explain why you think your refusal is unfair or extraordinary.

> What should we do next?

Interestingly, they also got you on V 4.2 (e), which is a pretty serious hit. They didn't need to use that paragraph but they did anyway. It means even if you didn't have the credibility problems you would still face the lack of financial  reserves to establish that you are a genuine visitor.  Honestly, it looks like your application was misconceived, so whatever you do not, **do not apply again** without adequate representation.

Normally the prescription is to get a proper solicitor to represent future applications.  Given your financial situation this is not a valid option. The internet is not going to be a lot of help either.  You might consider approaching one of the advocacy groups that specialise in family/migrant situations. You can, for example, show your stuff to the [Southall Black Sisters](http://www.southallblacksisters.org.uk/) (who I *like* by the way) and see if they can refer you onward.

---

Background on the Manila Visa Section

The Manila Visa Section is thought to be a high performance unit, arguably the highest. They process applications for almost all of the far east. The assistants check *everything*, and the ECO's spend an average of 9 minutes on an application, almost *twice* the norm.

[image]

The Chief Inspector audited the family visitor visas processed by Manila in 2014. They got a relatively clean bill of health and even took on more spokes as a result. See "[An Inspection of Family Visitor Visa Applications](http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Family-Visits-Inspection-16.07.2015.pdf)" for the complete report.

---

See also [Do UK visits visa call your workplace for verification?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53198/do-uk-visits-visa-call-your-workplace-for-verification/53233#53233)

Comment: The reason why i was refused before (fiance visa ) was because my husband's company did not give him his payslips. He earns more than£30,000 a year which will show on his tax returns. I know his bank statements doesnt look promising but he earns a decent pay. At the time he printed that bank statements , he was not able to deposit some of his money. We r supposed to apply for a spousal but him being self employed he doesnt get any payslips.

Comment: @GoddezLouee that sounds like a very poor excuse - your spouse can certainly issue himself with payslips, as he will still pay tax and NI contributions.  Failing that, he can supply copies of his self assessment form, which will have his earnings on it. He can also request an "evidence of earnings" from the HMRC (called a SA302) which provides you with a HMRC backed proof of the past 4 years of your earnings.  Plenty of options available.

Comment: @Moo ooooh, nice one! The penny drops. The spouse's reluctance to provide that sort of information could have prompted the ECO to question the strength of the relationship. I missed that one. Shrewd you are. Now the penny drops, thanks!  Plus there's full guidance for the self-employed anyway :)

Comment: @moo thank u so much for that info. I guess we r just too naive that we dont know what to do.. and also we got confused about his work status that we dont know what category to fill up. He is self employed with hmrc. But he doesnt have a business. He works for a certain company as a groundworker. When we applied for the Fiance visa 2 yrs ago , we paid an agency to represent us . They did not give us these options u are telling us now. We got denied because we were not able to prove that he passed the financial requirement. .

Comment: We submitted a copy of his p60 that says he earned more than £22,000 in 2014 but we were not able to provide payslips.when isubmitted my application,i filled up the self employed category but the ECO asked for more docs that we couldnt provide such as unaudited accounts etc.. then the agency advised me to change it to Employee .this is where the confusion started

Comment: @GoddezLouee OMG, Oh dear! You used an agency???  You didn't tell us that.  Oh heavens, that changes the landscape :(

Comment: @moo That Agency messed up my application. Their job was to assist us on  what was the best way to do but they didnt. Me and my husband didnt know a thing about visas thats why we paid an agency to do it for us. Maybe i Should show u the copy of the decision so that u will full understand my situation.

Comment: @GoddezLouee, no because we're a travel site and fiance questions go on Expats. http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions you can post your fiance refusal there. Did you use an agency for your visit visa?  Oh dear :(

Comment: @GAYOT FOW  yeah my situation is too complicated i dont know where to start to explain. Sorry..ok i will post the letter on Expats.

Comment: @GoddezLouee you will need a ask a new question, a different one.  Something like "Should I use a visa agency?" and then describe your visit visa process with the agency :(

Comment: @Gayot Fow i didnt use an agency with my visit visa. My husband's friend is also married to a filipina and they advised us why dont we try to apply for a tourist visa cos the wife got approved with her application. Her husband do not have work and he doesnt have a house in england. The only savings they have shown the embassy is P150,000. So she gave me requirements to submit. I was a bit confident on this one coz i was thinking "if her husband doesnt work and dont own a house i have a better chance of getting a visa. So thats what i did. She got a 2 yr multiple visa and i got refused 

Comment: You can come to chat and then ping me.

Comment: @Gayot Fow i tried to go on chat but a msg popped up saying im suspended 

Comment: @GoddezLouee, well that's not very nice of them, please go to META and find out why. Ask them at this http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/ where the higher-ups can see it, thanks.

Comment: @Gayot Fow can u ping me instead? Thanks